# rotating array causing time limit exception

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting a leetcode problem, rotate array, and the solution I'm trying is being accepted when I run the code but not when I submit it, despite the fact that this solution is being suggested online.
Problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/

My solution:

```
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
  k = k % nums.length
  let count = 0
  while (count < k) {
    nums.unshift(nums.pop())
    count++
  }
}
```

Edit: Problem solved thanks to the comments!

Comment: You're making the JS engine to really work hard, every time you unshift a member to an array, it's re-indexed (time consuming is negligible with small arrays, but when rotating real large arrays, the used time increases significantly). Instead, unshift only once, with a splice from the end of the array.

Comment: Use `splice` to extract all the right numbers, then rejoin those in front of the left: `nums = nums.splice(nums.length - k).concat(nums);`